# Join two rows based on two different ids

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently trying to join rows from a table on our SQL Server being loaded from our Syslog server. The table lists the VPN sessions of our users and always contains two rows for a session: Event 2201 is logged for the session start and 2202 when the session terminates.

```
+---------------------+---------+----------+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| eventdatetime       | eventid | username | srcip           | virtual_ip  | rx       | tx        |
+---------------------+---------+----------+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 2020-11-24 06:22:05 | 2201    | abc1234  | 111.222.333.444 | 172.16.10.2 | NULL     | NULL      |
| 2020-11-24 13:15:17 | 2201    | abc1234  | 111.222.333.444 | 172.16.10.4 | NULL     | NULL      |
| 2020-11-24 13:15:27 | 2202    | abc1234  | 111.222.333.444 | 172.16.10.2 | 74411108 | 655423421 |
| 2020-11-24 14:40:45 | 2202    | abc1234  | 111.222.333.444 | 172.16.10.4 | 22629095 | 175651830 |
| 2020-11-24 20:07:53 | 2201    | abc1234  | 111.222.333.444 | 172.16.10.2 | NULL     | NULL      |
| 2020-11-24 20:11:45 | 2202    | abc1234  | 111.222.333.444 | 172.16.10.2 | 1086188  | 5786362   |
| 2020-11-21 10:39:59 | 2201    | def5678  | 55.66.77.88     | 172.16.10.2 | NULL     | NULL      |
| 2020-11-21 11:26:49 | 2202    | def5678  | 55.66.77.88     | 172.16.10.2 | 25364309 | 40329362  |
| 2020-11-22 10:07:51 | 2201    | def5678  | 55.66.77.88     | 172.16.10.2 | NULL     | NULL      |
| 2020-11-22 10:33:15 | 2202    | def5678  | 55.66.77.88     | 172.16.10.2 | 7929825  | 34662648  |
+---------------------+---------+----------+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------+

CREATE TABLE syslog
(
    eventdatetime datetime NOT NULL,
    eventid smallint NOT NULL,
    username varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    srcip varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    virtual_ip varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    rx int NULL,
    tx int NULL
)
```

I however cannot just sort the table by date and time since users can create multiple sessions on different devices. Above table shows such an event in the first four rows.
values for username, srcip and virtual_ip are the same for a session but I'll have two timestamps and two event ids.

How can I combine those two rows from a session so that I get an output like that:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| start               | end                 | username | srcip           | virtual_ip  | rx       | tx        |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 2020-11-24 06:22:05 | 2020-11-24 13:15:27 | abc1234  | 111.222.333.444 | 172.16.10.2 | 74411108 | 655423421 |
| 2020-11-24 13:15:17 | 2020-11-24 14:40:45 | abc1234  | 111.222.333.444 | 172.16.10.4 | 22629095 | 175651830 |
| 2020-11-21 10:39:59 | 2020-11-21 11:26:49 | def5678  | 55.66.77.88     | 172.16.10.2 | 7929825  | 34662648  |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: According to your example, there are three events per Session aof user abc1234

Comment: However, I would suggest to use a cte where you create a rownumber such as `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY username, srcip, virtual_ip ORDER BY eventdatetime)` - afterwards you can select all rows from your cte with `rn = 1` and left join this again to your cte with rn 2 (or similar since in your example the rn for user def5678 will reach 4).

Comment: Do you not have an device identifier in your table?

Comment: @Tyron78 Yes, correct, two overlapping for a bunch of seconds and a third one later.

Comment: @PeterSmith Unfortunately not. The row from the Syslog server is generated from our firewall and I there's no way to alter the output. The full line looks like the following: `id="2201" severity="info" sys="SecureNet" sub="vpn" event="Connection started" username="abc1234" variant="ssl" srcip="111.222.333.444" virtual_ip="172.16.10.2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT [Start]
      ,[End]
      ,[username]
      ,[srcip]
      ,[virtual_ip]
      ,rx
      ,tx
FROM( 
SELECT [eventdatetime] AS [Start]
      ,LEAD(eventdatetime) OVER (ORDER BY [username], virtual_ip, eventdatetime) AS [End]
      ,[eventid]
      ,[username]
      ,[srcip]
      ,[virtual_ip]
      ,LEAD([rx]) OVER (ORDER BY [username], virtual_ip, eventdatetime) rx
      ,LEAD([tx]) OVER (ORDER BY [username], virtual_ip, eventdatetime) tx
  FROM [Test].[dbo].[syslog]) A
  WHERE eventid =2201
  ORDER BY[username], virtual_ip, [End]
```

Comment: Nice! But shouldn't the srcip be included in the ORDER BY of the WindowFunctions as well? After all, it might happen, that an user connects with multiple devices...

Answer (score 0):

I have almost what Tyron78 ​​was talking about with a few minor changes. In my case, I used join
table syslog to table syslog may not be the best option and you can use a nested query instead, or split the cte into two queries.

Here is my code:

```
USE Test
GO

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                [Start].[username], 
                [Start].[srcip], 
                [Start].[virtual_ip]
            ORDER BY 
                [Start].[eventdatetime]
        ) [row_num],
        [Start].[eventdatetime] AS [start],
        [End].[eventdatetime] AS [end],
        [Start].[username],
        [Start].[srcip],
        [Start].[virtual_ip],
        [End].[rx],
        [End].[tx]
    FROM [syslog] AS [Start]
        INNER JOIN [syslog] AS [End] ON [Start].[username] = [End].[username]
            AND [Start].[srcip] = [End].[srcip]
            AND [Start].[virtual_ip] = [End].[virtual_ip]
            AND [End].[eventid] = 2202
    WHERE [Start].[eventid] = 2201
)
SELECT [start], [end], [username], [srcip], [virtual_ip], [rx], [tx] FROM cte WHERE row_num = 1
```

Also, this code can be moved in to a view.

Comment: This doesn't return all rows: I have 310 rows in my current sample table and while @Sai's solution returns the correct amount of 155, the CTE solution only returns 52. It seems that the entries are grouped to the first IP per user and day. If the user connects multiple times and re-uses the IP, the rows are not shown. If I add [Start].[eventdatetime] or [End].[eventdatetime] to the PARTITION BY clause, I get the correct amount of rows but then either the start times are duplicated or the end times.